# What is the source of the (oft-quoted) phrase "אתיות מחכימות"

Tags: sources-mekorot

The phrase "אתיות מחכימות" is often bandied about. What is the source? Is this meant to be taken literally? Does it apply to נ"ך as well as תורה? What about דברי חז"ל?

Comment: Welcome, nosh. Haven't time to write up an answer now but please look at https://forum.otzar.org/viewtopic.php?t=43026